# Element is getting a margin at the bottom undesired

Tags: css, reactjs

```
    .home{
        height: 100vh;
        &__logo{
            margin: 5vh auto 4.5rem auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            svg{
             height: 2rem;
            }
        }
    &__container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    &__text{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background-position: left;
        align-items: center;
        &--h1{
         margin: 2rem 1.5rem;
         text-align: center;

        }
        &--btn{
            button{
              padding:1.2rem 3rem;
            }
        }


    }

    &__img{
        margin-top: 5rem;
        width: 95vw;
        position: relative;
        right: 2rem;
        height: 60vh;

      img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 
      }

    &--1{
        display: none;

    }

    }
}
```

i'm getting a margin below the image that i can't get off. I want the image to stay at the size of the bottom of the screen, not to make the user scroll.

It should not have any margin or scrolling. I want to fit the image exactly at the bottom of the screen
[image]

Comment: It's difficult to help without a sandbox.

Comment: I'm sorry, don't know what sandbox means in english, can you explain it to me?

Comment: There are many options available to create a sandbox (eg. https://codesandbox.io/). Sandbox explanation: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that your `body` has a `margin` on all directions.  You can use

```
body { margin: 0 }
```

to remove it and try again. Also, inspect your element using the developer's tool to look at the computed width and height for the `html`, `body`, and the containers down to your `img`. Look at the values (and also check for margin and padding), and especially, the height and vertical margin and padding if the image is scrolling.

You can also use `calc()`:

```
img { height: calc(100% - 16px) }
```

so that your image is not as tall.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, but i will keep on trying find where the margins is coming from